# How to install kezmenu

Tags: python, module, installation

Kezmenu can be found here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/KezMenu/. I've tried a few things like putting the whole .tar.gz file in site-packages and then unpacking it to a .tar, then the folder and nothing gave me any results. Near the bottom I think it says something about easy_install but i'm not sure how to install or work that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pip for installing.

write this in comand promt.

pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/K/KezMenu/KezMenu-0.3.0-py2.5.egg

see this site:https://www.versioneye.com/python/kezmenu/0.3.0

Comment: I got 'pip' not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I assume I need to install pip, how exactly do I do that?

Comment: for installing pip use this link: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html